# MySQL IF THEN in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have table with a enum column with possible values of 'relative' and 'absolute'. There maybe duplicate rows with the difference being that column.

So normally I would select a row with the 'absolute' value but I need and if caluse to check if there is a 'duplicate' row where the column is 'relative' and then select that row instead (if there is a reletive row, there will always be absolute row too)

pseudo code:

```
select *
  from table
  where non_unique_col = 123
    and IF (has result row with 'relative'
        then return that row
        else return 'absolute' row)
```

Comment: Can you add the structure of the database to your question?

Comment: You could use `ORDER BY` on that column and since R/A are different letters the 'correct one' should come up. No need to do weird stuff here.

Comment: Do you just need one row to come back from this query?

Comment: @EinoT: please see my proposed answer, if I understood your question correctly it might help you

Comment: Yes I do need several rows to come out. The rows themselves have no actual relation but for example the non_unique_col could be "user_id" and there can be one or two rows for each user. Now if there is two the other on has that enum field with value 'absolute' and the other one 'relative' in that case I need the resulting row to be the one with the 'relative' but I need the rows from "each user" so multiple rows.

Comment: Use COALESCE(), and outer join the table itself on the 'relative' criterion

Comment: Can you make an actual usage example?

Comment: @EinoT: edited my answer to be more generic, see if it helps.

Comment: @EinoT: also, could you please provide precise table structure and some example data, or better, an sqlfiddle of it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `non_unique_col` = 123
ORDER BY `absolute_relative_col` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This way, if there is exactly one result, no problem the, if there are more, you get the 'relative' one.

EDIT:

As per @Travesty3 suggestion, I'd like to underline that this query is made on the assumption that `(non_unique_col + absolute_relative_col)` makes a `unique_col`, which is based on OP statements that

> There maybe duplicate rows with the difference being that column

and

> if there is a relative row, there will always be absolute row too

EDIT 2:

A more generic solution could be the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` as t1
JOIN (
  SELECT non_unique_col, absolute_relative_col
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `absolute_relative_col` = 'relative'
) as t2 USING (non_unique_col)
WHERE t2.absolute_relative_col = 'relative' OR (
  t2.absolute_relative_col IS NULL
  AND t1.absolute_relative_col = 'absolute'
)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing, but what if he wants more than one row to come back?

Comment: Well, I guess we can adjust the query, I based mine from OP example.

Comment: @AmazingDreams: How do you know how big the result set will be? OP hasn't said anything about the size of the table.

Comment: If the OP has the "ID" of the row, like the `123` in the example, no need to use PHP for filtering.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: I don't see where, in the original question, OP indicated that `123` is the ID of the row. In fact, just the opposite, he has named it **non_unique_col**.

Comment: That is what I am saying, the OP should decide for himself if my proposed 'solution' (which it is only half, as I stated myself), is enough.

Comment: In the OP example, he used `non_unique_col = 123`, obviously `123` is some placeholder, but there will be only at most 2 rows with `non_unique_col = 123`, as per what the OP said: **There maybe duplicate rows with the difference being that column**

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to troll. I just think you're assuming too much. OP did not indicate that there will be at most 2 rows with `non_unique_col = 123`. Granted, that may be true, but I would have asked first or indicated that I was making that assumption in my answer.

Comment: @Travesty3: I assumed that from both the OP example and his statement that **There maybe duplicate rows with the difference being that column**, he also says **if there is a relative row, there will always be absolute row too**, from these statements it seems to me that (non_unique_col + absolute_relative_col) is unique.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: Please don't think I'm attacking you in any way. I wasn't trying to take away from your answer in any way. I was about to post the same thing myself. I was trying to suggest a way that you could improve it. It's still an assumption that you're making. As such, you should either ask the OP in order to make sure, or indicate in your answer that you're making that assumption, so this solution only works if that assumption is true. If you wanted to go the extra mile, you could come up with a secondary solution for a case where your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Travesty3: never took it as a personal attack =) are you perhaps suggesting that I should explicitely state my assumptions?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: Yes, or ask in comments before answering.

Answer (score 0):

The following (untested) query should return what you want, but as with most queries that use subqueries, I don't think it is very efficient.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `non_unique_col`=123 
AND ( 
    (`relativity` = 'relative') 
    OR (`relativity` = 'absolute' 
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM `table` 
            WHERE `non_unique_col`=123 
            AND `relativity`='relative'
        )
    )
);
```

See [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

Edit: If you would want to create a list of this (e.g. without the id), then you would write something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` as a 
WHERE (`relativity` = 'relative') 
OR (
    `relativity` = 'absolute' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM `table` as b 
        WHERE a.`non_unique_col`=b.`non_unique_col` 
        AND `relativity`='relative'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT non_unique_col nuc, 
           MAX(absolute_relative_col) rec 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY non_unique_col 
) AS t ON nuc=non_unique_col AND rec=absolute_relative_col
-- (@Zessx: second condition is still part of the INNER JOIN ...)
```

**EDIT**:

But I like the idea with COALESCE (see comment of Strawberry, above!) **much better**:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN ( 
 SELECT COALESCE(b.id,a.id) FROM tablel a 
 LEFT JOIN tbl b ON b.non_unique_col=a.non_unique_col
                AND b.absolute_relative_col='relative'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the row are identical apart from the relative or absolute part *and* if you require only on row for each non_unique_column value, why not simply using:

```
select non_unique_col, max(rel_or_abs), extra_data from tbl
group by non_unique_col;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b97fc0/2